# PHP Remote Debugging using XDebug

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging, eclipse-pdt

I've got a lot of questions about how to debug php-files with xdebug and eclipse on a remote server.

**What I would like to achieve is**:
I have a remote server (with WAMPP (appache (Port 8502), php, mysql (Port 8501), etc)) and I would like to debug the php-files with Eclipse PDT from my local PC.

**I prepared the following things**:

- Installed Eclipse PDT (Build id:
  20100617-1415) on my local PC
- Installed and activated xdebug on the
  remote server (available at (lets
  say) 111.111.111.111:8502) with the
  following configuration within the
  php.ini

---

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\TYPO3_4.4.6\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:/xampp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
xdebug.remote_log="C:\TYPO3_4.4.6\tmp\xdebug\xdebug_remote.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```

---

- In Eclipse I added the server in
  "Window - PHP - PHP Servers" with the
  URL "http://111.111.111.111:8502" and
  the Path Mapping - Path on Server:
  "C:\TYPO3_4.4.6\htdocs" and Path in
  Workspace: "/debug_test" (I created a
  PHP Project named "debug_test").
- I also changed the PHP - Debug to the following:

  - PHP-Debugger: XDebug
  - Server: 111.111.111.111
  - PHP Executable None Defined
- Next I added the debug configuration (PHP Web Page):

  - Server Debugger: XDebug
  - PHP Server: 111.111.111.111
  - File: /debug_test/debug.php
  - Break at first line: off
  - Auto Generate: on
- I created the file debug.php on the Remote Server at C:\TYPO3_4.4.6\htdocs\debug_test\ and within my PHP Project ("debug_test").

If I now run "Debug" and choose my Configuration File, the Webpage pops up (in an external browser) with the URL http://111.111.111.111:8502/debug_test/debug.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=129657398681515 and the page is (fully) loaded as a normal page, but there is no way to debug it. Even If I switch to the PHP Debug - View and insert any breakpoints or things like this, there is nothing like debugging.

How do I get to the point that I can do remote debugging with xdebug and eclipse pdt?

Cheers,
Cheeesi

Comment: Good question, I want to know that answer too

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your XDebug-Client / PC can be reached by 127.0.0.1 from your server?

B/c if I understand you correctly the your server is not installed on your PC. OTOH then I'm wondering about how you set up ypur XAMPP-system. B/c then usually all your stuff is locally installed.

Also the Browser's behaviour is important. If after invoking an XDebug-session through Eclipse your site is fully loaded, then your XDebug-Client in Eclipse couldn't reach your server. If you see your browser trying to load the page but it's stalling, then your client could tell the server to start an XDebug-session but your XDebug on the server couldn't connect back.

Your port 8502 that you specify for your server is also bit odd, but could be correct, given the corresponding configurations.

Best regards

Raffael

EDIT: and for a first try you should enable break on first line

Comment: Hi Raffael, thanks for the fast response! Do you come to the point that my PC can't be reached by the Server, because within the XDebug-Config the remote host is set to 127.0.0.1?      The XAMPP (in fact it is wampp that comes with the typo3 winstaller) is installed on the server. The Server is reachable through the internet using the port 8502.         If I invoke the debugging using the above explained debug-config, the browser loads the site completely. Is there a possibility to see, whether Eclipse can reach the xdebug-component on the server?

Comment: Hey Cheesi ... see, 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost, which would be necessary for example if the apache would be running on the same PC and OS as your Eclipse. In your case as your are actually using a remote server 127.0.0.1 cannot be the propper IP. I guess you can log on to the server using Putty or something like that. Then try netstat -atpn for example to find out which IP your server knows you by. So in that case you're server cannot reach you. But given your symptoms it seems like you can't reach the server as well. Try to forego 8502 as long as no admin told you to do so. Best